# Show map tiles made in MapTiler in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, tiles, png, xyz, tile-map-service

I converted GeoTIFF to png-tiles using MapTiler. Here is the folder structure:
[image]

Now I'm trying to add this folder with png-tiles to OpenLayers as XYZ source:

```
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      attributions: 'Rendered with <a href="https://www.maptiler.com/desktop/">MapTiler Desktop</a>',
      url: "http://localhost:80/png_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      tilePixelRatio: 1.00000000
    })
  })
```

But the raster is not displayed, and there are errors in the browser console:
[image]

And I don't have folders with such names either.

I also tried to specify in the source the ip and port of the live server, with which I run my code (I use Visual Studio Code with built-in live-server, but I also have Apache on port 80 on my host):

```
url: "http://localhost:5500/data/png_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

But there is no result either.
I'm new to web mapping and just want to understand how to include a local source of png tiles in OpenLayers.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `openlayers.html` file, created by MapTiler? There you can see all the necessary code to display tiles with OpenLayers, only `url` has to be replaced with the `url` of your server.

Comment: How many tiles do you have for zoom level 8?  If your coverage is limited to the four tiles listed at zoom level 11 there would be no more than two tiles at zoom level 8 (8/184/82 and 8/185/82)  If coverage starts at level 11 you should specify that as minZoom, together with the extent covered.